NBodySimulation with pair-wise force a function of acceleration?
How does one construct an NBodySimulation in which the custom PairwiseForce law involves acceleration?
I'm attempting to simulate a 3 pairs (electron and proton) of bodies hence a 6 body problem based on a version of Weber electrodynamics force -- where one of the bodies (an electron) is undergoing a driving function (Hertzian dipole hence sine).  However, the Weber force is a function of not only relative position and relative velocity but also of relative acceleration between the paired bodies.
Unfortunately, the state vector for a body in NBodySimulation does not contain an acceleration vector.
PS:  I understand that the driving function may not be supported by ExternalForce but I may be able to change the Charge to identify the electron within the PairwiseForce function and conditionally apply the driving function.

Acceleration-dependent forces aren't compatible with Newtonian mechanics (because the state is completely determined by positions and velocities). But NBodySimulation assumes Newton's Second and Third Laws are valid, so this problem is not treatable they way you want. You may be able to get farther using NDSolve directly - but even then you may run into the question of how to state the initial conditions consistently.
